# Can I flip these words and keep the gist?

Tags: word-order

In the text:

> "Clinical trials found the vaccine to work well, but the company has long struggled with manufacturing. Here’s the latest on the pandemic." (From [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/06/07/health/novavax-covid-vaccine.html))

Can I rewrite it as:

> "Clinical trials found the vaccine to work well, but the company has STRUGGLED LONG with manufacturing. Here’s the latest on the pandemic.

and keep the same semantics?

Comment: "Has struggled long" sounds old-fashioned and poetical; not really suitable for a medical text.

Comment: Only one 'p' in 'flip'.

Answer (score 2):

The past participles ***known*** and ***argued*** are far more common than ***struggled*** after ***long***, so let's check [the usage figures](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20long%20known%20that%2Chave%20known%20long%20that%2Chave%20long%20argued%20that%2Chave%20argued%20long%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20long%20known%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20known%20long%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20long%20argued%20that%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20long%20known%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20known%20long%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20long%20argued%20that%3B%2Cc0) for those...

[image]

Note that this use of "fronted" adverbial ***long*** before the past participle in a Perfect verb form *[subject] **has long** [verbed]* is a formal / literary / dated construction that rarely occurs in relaxed conversational contexts today. We usually rephrase to *[subject] has [verbed] **for a long time*** or similar.

---

Note that many other "adverbial qualifiers" work exactly the same way in this construction - ***often, seldom, rarely, never***, for example, nearly always come *before* the verb, as with ***long***. But [*some* adverbial elements](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20repeatedly%20said%20that%2Chave%20said%20repeatedly%20that%2C%28%28have%20occasionally%20worked%29*10%29%2C%28%28have%20worked%20occasionally%29*10%29&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) can go in either position without affecting the meaning. For example...

[image]

...where I multiplied the ***worked occasionally / occasionally worked*** figures by 10 to make them fit the above chart, since we're only interested in the *relative ratios* of the two sequences here, not their *absolute* prevalence.

---

TL;DR:  The cited use of ***long*** is a "frozen form" that's no longer "productive", so you can't expect variations of it to be idiomatic.